# Create Table script from exisiting table using Toad

Tags: database, oracle, toad, create-table

I am new to toad and certainly db management if not my job.
I am Java Developer, where I have a scenario to create tables in test environment which are exact copy of another environment from another db.

I have access to both tables with all permissions.
All I need to do is, Get an exact copy of CREATE Table structure from Dev environment table to test environment.

Please guide me to do this.

Db: Oracle
Toad Free ware 11.x

Note: Table data is not required. Needed only table columns and constraints etc.

Comment: Do you want the data as well?  Is this a one-off exercise or something you'll need to repeat on a regular basis?  Do ypu need a process which will also work for **TEST -> PRODUCTION** /

Comment: I don't need on regular basis. We are just doing for testing and we will not work on db side. rare scenarios.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hit <kbd>F4</kbd> after entering your table name -> Click on Script tab, you'll get the DDL statements.